# Unlock zooming after scrolling in maps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have these two methods that I use to lock onto the user's location in Maps, and it works perfectly...

However, I guess it works too well lol, whenever I the user moves the map to look else where on the map... It forces the user back to the spot were the current location is at.

So I guess my question is, how can i disable the lock to user location, after the user scrolls in the map.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

     // more code here that i didn't post

     [self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self 
                            forKeyPath:@"location" 
                       options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) 
                       context:NULL];
    }



- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath  
                  ofObject:(id)object  
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change  
                   context:(void *)context {  

    if ([self.mapView showsUserLocation]) {  

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;  

    MKCoordinateSpan span; 
    span.latitudeDelta  = 1; // Change these values to change the zoom
    span.longitudeDelta = 1; 
    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i think i figured it out... the way i am currently doing it above seems to be the hard way... in iOS 5 they allow use to use this method and it worked like a charm

```
[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```